# What is the maximum color value in GLSL unsinged int?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my fragment shader, I need to use `uvec4`.

My shader:

```
layout (location = 0) out uvec4 final_color;
void main(void) {

    final_color.r = 0;
    final_color.g = 4294967295;
    final_color.b = 0;
    return;
}
```

I think, this will be green because unsigned_int max is 4294967295. (2^32-1) but it is just black.
I tried singed int max, 2147483647, it's black too. but 2137483648 works. Where is the boundary?

I want know max value, like 255(8bit) or 1.0f(float, vec4).

Comment: What is the format (see [Image Format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format)) of the framebuffer? Why do you want to use the data type `uvec4`? If the farmebuffer has (unsigned normalized) floating point format, then use the data type `vec4` and set the color channels in range [0.0, 1.0].

Comment: How do you print the colors afterwards? Or are you writing directly to the backbuffer? In general, it is undefined behavior to output data in a format that doesn't match the framebuffer format.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i need some 'delicate' calculate. if i use vec4, it make a little error. In my case, floating point operation is not working perfectly.
and i do nothing to framebuffer.... default is only allow vec4? i'll see that.

Comment: @BDL  i don't touch framebuffer... my program draw result to window directly. I need to see it. thanks.

Comment: @Redwings: You can't write uvec4 to the default framebuffer. Usually, the default framebuffer will have a bit-depth of 8bits per channel anyway, it is very unlikely that with a maximum precision of 1/256 you get into floating point errors. If the problem is your calculation inside the shader -> calculate in uint and cast to float before returning.

Comment: The max should be 255. Any value higher than that should be interpreted as 255, I think.

Comment: @BDL How can i cast uint->float? many uint value is more than 2100000000 .... any float type can store that, uint/uint is not float. how can i do it?  or , can i get not normalized value? my texture is unsigned short, but value from glsl func texture() return is more than 2100000000.

Comment: @Redwings: I guess we still have a major misunderstanding. A backbuffer stores values in range [0,1] with a resolution of 1/256 (normalized byte). If you want to store something else than that, you need a custom framebuffer. If you use a int framebuffer, then talking about colors ("it is green") does not make any sense. It is also impossible that you read from a unsigned short texture and get a value outside of [0, 2^16-1=65535]. If you get other values, you are doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> my program draw result to window directly. I need to see it.

Well, you can't. A `uvec4` contains unsigned, 32-bit integers. That output can *only* be written to an image that uses an unsigned integer [image format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats). Note that this is *different* from a normalized integer image format.

You cannot create a default framebuffer that contains non-normalized integers, only floats and normalized integers. So you can't "see it".

As such, that value is not a "color"; it's just data stored in a texture. What it means is entirely up to how you will eventually use the value in that texture to get something displayable.